# Replacing JMS with Hazelcast?

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic, apache-camel, hazelcast

We are currently running a distributed Java application connected by a set of JMS queues (no topics). The Java application makes heavy use of the Apache Camel framework, which is also used to communicate via JMS. As JMS provider we have ActiveMQ in use. Our requirements on the queuing solution are quite basic in terms of features - somehow comparable to local Java queues and Camel SEDA queues:

1. The queues need to be highly available
2. In average the message is quite small (several KB), but there must not be a restriction on the size (i.e., a small percentage of the messages transferred have several MBs)
3. Delivery must be "exactly once" (Amazon SQS, for example, guarantees "at least once" only, which is not acceptable for us)

We do not require persistent queues, since messages are stored in a database before entering the queuing system. So far, ActiveMQ is working quite well for us after spending some time on the setup. However, there are two issues because of which we are searching for a different solution:

- We currently achieve high-availability by running AMQ in JDBC Master-Slave-Mode. Failovers work quite ok, but not as transparent as desired.
- The JDBC store has a negative impact on performance, especially if we transfer larger messages (>= 2-3 MBs) over several (> 6) queues. Furthermore, we have the feeling to unnecessarily bother our database.

We know that AMQ supports HA using Zookeeper since version 5.9. Some time ago, however, we started to consider/evaluate Hazelcast as a replacement for AMQ. So long, Hazelcast looks quite charming, since it seems to fulfill all of our requirements and seems to be much simpler to run than AMQ with Zookeeper. Furthermore, Camel provides nice support for using Hazelcast as queuing solution via its Hazelcast SEDA features. Given the fact that Hazelcast seems to be the perfect replacement for AMQ for us, we somehow wonder that there is not much information available on the Web discussing Hazelcast as a (serious) replacement for JMS. Thus, we would like to know:

- Are there any drawbacks from replacing JMS with Hazelcast (performance, reliability,...)?
- Has anyone experienced problems with multi-MB messages in Hazelcast?
- Has anyone experienced any reliability issues with Hazelcast? We are still using 2.6 at the moment (because the Camel component is currently using that version) and have [daemonized](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) it on Ubuntu. So far it seems to be running flawlessly, but some additional experiences would be nice to hear.

Comment: Go for it. Hazelcast is quite reliable in enterprise environments. I have used Camel, Fuse ESB and Hazelcast and can recommend all of them highly.

Comment: Check out HazelcastMQ.